# Is overloading a base class function bad practice?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

Suppose I have a base class `MySet`:

```
class MySet {
    std::vector<int> set;
public:
    bool disjoint(const MySet &other) const {
        // loop over entire set and see if any elements
        //    are in other.set
    }
};
```

And I have a derived class `SortedRange`:

```
class SortedRange : public MySet {
    // All integers between two limits
public:
    using MySet::disjoint;
    bool disjoint(const SortedRange &other) const {
         return set.first() > other.set.last()
                 || other.set.first() > set.last();
    }
};
```

The `disjoint` method in `MySet` will work for every class that derives from `MySet`, but when finding the disjointness between two `SortedRanges` it makes sense to overload the `disjoint` method in the derived class:

```
int main() {
    MySet* base = new Set();
    SortedRange* derived = new SortedRange();

    derived->disjoint(*derived); // Can use optimized disjoint function
    derived->disjoint(*base); // Should fall back on base disjoint function
}
```

I've read that [name hiding](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/c-name-hiding/) was added in for good reason, and that subverting it in this way is bad practice.

Is there a better way to implement something like this without subverting name hiding?

Comment: The ability to override a method in a subclass is one of the basic ideas of OO programming. The base class provides a default method, but subclasses can override it if they need to specialize in some way.

Comment: Yes, it's bad practice. A more reasonable design would be to avoid inheritance completely. In fact, I don't think you need your classes at all. Just use `std::set` and turn `disjoint` into a non-member function operating on iterators or on two `std::set`s (whatever is appropriate for your problem).

Comment: @Barmar and others. He's asking about overloading, not overriding.

Comment: @ChristianHackl This is just a simple example. What if I have more complicated classes that are not implemented in the standard library?

Comment: @Barmar: Double dispatch is not naturally supported by C++, yet this is what you effectively need when a `virtual` member function has a parameter of its own base-class type. As a result, you have to manually check the dynamic type of the parameter with `typeid` / `dynamic_cast` in every overriding function, because every combination of ConcreteClassX and ConcreteClassY may need specialised behaviour. I don't think this can ever lead to a really clean design.

Comment: @MikeBorkland I do mean overload and not override. In fact, name hiding would still occur if  `MySet::disjoint` were made virtual.

Comment: @ConfusedByCode: The standard library is designed to be extensible with your own containers, your own algorithms and your own iterators. So the answer to your question is: just write your own container class and make its interface compatible (providing `begin()` / `end()` and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason name hiding was introduced was to handle the case where we have:

```
class Base {
    // stuff
};

class Derived : public Base {
    // more stuff
public:
    static int foo(int);
};
```

and there is a call to `Derived::foo()` with a literal `'a'` as argument.  Then the developer of `Base` adds a new private function `Base::foo(char)`.  Without name hiding, the program suddenly stops compiling - the call to `Derived::foo` resolves to the private member in `Base`.  Name hiding prevents this.

The above is not a problem in your example (because `using` means that you already knew about `foo`/`disjoint`), so overloading a base class member function is not intrinsically bad.

However, your motivating example is not very motivating - a `SortedRange` doesn't feel like it isA `MySet`.  I doubt inheritance is the right approach.  (And unless a `SortedRange` is supposed to represent *all* integers between two limits, your `disjoint` implementation is incorrect - it will return `[1, 3, 5]` as not disjoint with `[2, 4, 6]`)